# Sheets Circular Dependency Error - Dynamic Item Score

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I keep running into a circular dependency in my spreadsheet which is scoring up items and giving a level based off of the total score, whilst at the same time, providing a dynamic score for a certain item that is always supposed to increase your level by 1.

This is done by having a list of items that are summed up to their total score, the total score is then looked up in a table and returns your level. The dynamic item score is done by  calculating the difference between your current score and the score required to reach the next level. Tier 1 is +1level, Tier2 = +2 levels, Tier3 = +3 levels, and the tier you're currently using is selected by the user via a checkbox.

I'd rather not resort to scripts or anything, but I'm at a very beginner level with spreadsheets and can't figure out a way around this error, despite it seeming so simple to me.

My main spreadsheet is extremely convoluted so I've created and example sheet here that I'll be able to convert to my main one if resolved to simplify the process.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17KSjLt9x7k7R8aE2bM8JryglYWcykF8zMwUNaL4gL0A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @BigBen I appreciate that, however, spreadsheets are spreadsheets. They mostly use the same formulas, at least the formulas I'm using anyway and they both have circular dependency/reference errors so I don't see the harm in using both sheets and excel tags?

Comment: Except that you are ignoring the instructions on the tags to not cross use them.  This is the site policy.

Comment: @ScottCraner So it's not allowed to cross use excel/google-sheets at all, or would it be okay if I copy pasted the sheets into an excel spreadsheet and posted the screenshot here too?

Comment: The tags specifically state that you should not use them together.  And circular references are going to be dealt with differently, depending on which you are using.  In Excel you can allow them, Google sheets you cannot(unless they changed that recently)

Comment: @ScottCraner I see, I apologise then, I've always bounced between excel and sheets depending on the device im using so I've never known a real difference. 

You can allow them in Sheets, you just have to enable iterative calculations in the settings. I just wasn't sure if that was the best way of getting around the error, or rather the "proper" way and I wasn't sure if that setting was saved to the sheet so I didn't have to explain to anyone using the sheet to go and enable that setting to make it work.